# Where does integral concept come from?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have been searching for days to find why Newton offered an anti-derivative function to find the area under the curve. What was the reason for searching such a function? Was it just mathematical curiosity or was there a solid reason for that?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the mathematical concept itself or a historical explanation of how Newton came upon it?

Comment: I was watching a bunch of videos where it says that in order to find the area under the curve Newton started to think about an anti-derivative of that function. I am just trying to understand what was the reason for searching an anti-derivative?

Comment: I would say the theory of integration in Newton's time was a development beyond the quadrature technique known to the ancient Greeks. His achievement -- with the concept of a derivative already understood -- was to observe that the area $A(x)$ under the "curve" $y = f(x)$ above the segment $[a,x]$ had the property $\frac{dA}{dx}(x) = f(x)$. I don't know the precise "reason for searching" but it is clear that Newton was exceptional in terms of scientific observation.

Comment: Historically when searching for the area $A(f(x),[0,t])$ under $f(x)=x^n,x \in [0,t]$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ it is natural to search how $A(f(x),[0,t])$ transforms under $t \mapsto t+1$ or $t \mapsto 2t$. When those transformations are fully understood they give an explicit formula for the area.

Comment: Also as area is a geometric concept, Newton's geometrical interpretation of fluxions (derivatives) was amenable to making a connection.  Look at Newton's graphical proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I believe Newton's teacher Barrow already had obtained a form of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  If so, you should be asking where *Barrow* got the idea.

Comment: Newton was not the first mathematician to do so. Go back in the history, Cavalieri, Torricelli, and before ...